# "flag" ... like registry, file, process or variable ....anything what will alive relogon but not restart

Tags: windows, operating-system, bios

After updating Bios there is still only old version readable over WMI. Only after restart the new BIOS is applied and reflected to WMI. So before the restart we would like to set "flag" depending on the return code of bios update. This flag will be set only if return code is 0 or 3010 or ... and this flag should stay till the restart is done after restart the flag should not exist any more and real bios version will be tested. What do you recommend to use as a flag on Windows OS what will disappear after restart automaticall but will not be removed after relogon.
Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `RunServicesOnce` registry key (documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx)). According to the referenced web page the key will get deleted upon reboot.

Since you won't really want to run a program, you'd want to specify a program that doesn't do anything. Maybe `CMD.EXE /C echo do nothing`.

Since this key isn't really designed for your use case, I recommend you test it pretty well.

Comment: Is the RunServicesOnce working well on Windows 7?
Have been inserting this registry, did a restart but the entry was not removed from registry.


Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
"BiosUpdate"="cmd.exe /c echo \"Bios update Flag will be automatically removed on next PC restart.\""

Comment: Don't know. Have never used it. Only know what documentation says. I suggest googling for RunServicesOnce and see what you find. You can download the AutoRuns program to see what it says about the RunServices/RunServicesOnce keys.Another approach might be to create a flag file and then use RunServices or RunServicesOnce to delete the file.